# Assign Unique id's across all documents and its children

Tags: solr

So the situation is as follows:

- Solr has a dataimport directly on the database
- I have a table *project* in a relationship to *unit*. A project can hold up to 5 units
- ID's are automatically generated from the database, starting by 1
- ID's are unique for each table but not across the database

Since Solr requires each document to have a unique ID I created a field *solrId* which gets its ID's from solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory.

However, the dataimport only fetches a few projects and no units whatsoever. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The relevant passages:

**solrconfig.xml**:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">solrId</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
....
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">wiensued-data-config.xml</str>
        <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

**managed-schema**:

```
<uniqueKey>solrId</uniqueKey>
<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
<!-- solrId is the real ID -->
<field name="solrId" type="uuid" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<!-- the ID from the database -->
<field name="id" type="int" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The dataimporthandler is configured to index id (from the table) into either projectId or unitId

The stacktrace is:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: [doc=null] missing required field: solrId
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:265)
at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand$1.next(AddUpdateCommand.java:212)
at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand$1.next(AddUpdateCommand.java:185)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:259)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:433)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1384)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocument(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:920)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:913)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:302)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:239)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:194)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:979)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1192)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:748)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:91)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:80)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:254)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:526)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:415)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:474)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:457)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, the solrId is provided as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get this fixed in your dih config, it will be just cleaner and easier.

Just prepend a 'p' to the project id to create the id, and supply that to solr. Likewise with the units (prepend 'u'). You get the idea:

```
 <entity name="project" pk="id" query="select concat('p', id) as solrid, ...
```

Of course the sql depends on your DB.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that! Thank you very much!